# Compare 2 fields from Standared object to 2 fields in Custom object and copy data

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to compare 2 fields from standard object **`Contract`** with two field in a custom object **`State_Rules__c`**.

1. If record type Name in **`Contract`** and the **`States__c`** match the
   **`State_Rules__c.States__c`** and
2. The Contract Record type name match either
   **`State_Rules__c.Financial_Due_Date__c`** or **`State_Rules__c.NOI_Due_Date__c`**.

Then copy **`NOI`** or **`Financial Due date`** from **`State_Rules__c`** custom object to **`Contract.Due_Date__c`**.

```
trigger CreateContract on Contract(before insert){
    map<string,Id> contr = new map<string,Id>();
    map<Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Contract.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
    for(Contract record : Trigger.new) {
        //if(record.RecordTypeId == '012630000004MBT')  //Financial
        if(rt_Map.get(record.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Financial')) {
            contr.put(record.States__c, null);
        }
        //else if(record.RecordTypeId =='012630000004MBO')  //NOI
        if(rt_Map.get(record.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('NOI')) {
            contr.put(record.States__c, null);
        }
    }
    List<State_Rule__c> StaRulList = new List<State_Rule__c>([select name from State_Rule__c where Name IN: contr.keySet()]);
    map<Id,State_Rule__c> StaRulMap = new map<Id,State_Rule__c>();
    for(State_Rule__c sr : StaRulList) {
        StaRulMap.put(sr.Id, sr);
    }
    // Copy the State Rules object fields to Contracted based 
    for(contract record: Trigger.new) {
        State_Rule__c sr = StaRulMap.get(record.States__c);
        if (contr.get(record.States__c) != null && rt_Map.get(record.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Financial')) {
            State_Rule__c stRulObj = new State_Rule__c();
            record.Due_Date__c = stRulObj.Financial_State_Date__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Not able to bring that financial due date from custom object (state_rules_c) to contact object due_date__c. I'm getting blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with this code, but your main issue is these two lines:

```
        State_Rule__c stRulObj = new State_Rule__c();
        record.Due_Date__c = stRulObj.Financial_State_Date__c;
```

`stRulObj` won't have any values because you've just instantiated it.
Perhaps you meant to use `sr` instead?